# In .HTA get page html with tags in upper case and attributes without quotes

Tags: javascript, activex, hta

I'm working on my small app in .HTA file with JavaScript. When I try to get all the html of current page, I get it with all the tags in upper case and attributes are without double quotes.

Simple example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9.0" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">Some text</div>
<script>
var html = document.querySelector('html').innerHTML;
alert(html);

var writeStream = new ActiveXObject('ADODB.Stream');
writeStream.Type = 2;
writeStream.Open();
writeStream.Charset = 'utf-8';
writeStream.WriteText(html);
writeStream.SaveToFile('index.html', 2);
writeStream.Close();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So the source code of `index.html` is:

```
<HEAD><TITLE>Test</TITLE>
<META content=ie=9.0 http-equiv=x-ua-compatible>
<META charset=utf-8></HEAD>
<BODY>
<DIV class=content>Some text</DIV>
<SCRIPT>
var html = document.querySelector('html').innerHTML;
alert(html);

var writeStream = new ActiveXObject('ADODB.Stream');
writeStream.Type = 2;
writeStream.Open();
writeStream.Charset = 'utf-8';
writeStream.WriteText(html);
writeStream.SaveToFile('index.html', 2);
writeStream.Close();
</SCRIPT>
</BODY>
```

But I need all the tags in lower case and attributes with double quotes as it's normally in HTML.

Comment: The old-school mark-up, you are running this on Win7 and IE8 ..?

Comment: Yes, you're right

Comment: Update to IE9, nothing you can do to this with IE8, unless you don't want to write your own HTML parser. The mark-up works though, even without quoted attribute values.

Comment: MS rendering engine returns uppercase tags.. You need to handle either if IE9+ no longer does that

Comment: Is the HTML on disk written in lowercase or uppercase? You could use the Scripting.FileSystemObject to read the file at `window.location`.